# Using a map to return something specific

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to learn the Python language and I tried working on a project with someone to better understand it.

Now the following piece of code was something my partner wrote, but when I load the project in PyCharm it underlines the code in red and the output also doesn't show what it's supposed to do.

So I have this piece of code:

```
class account_fiscal_position(osv.osv):
_name = 'account.fiscal.position'
_inherit = 'account.fiscal.position'

MAP_BTW_REGIME_KLANT_TOPACCOUNT = [(1, 'L3'),
                                   (2, 'C'),
                                   (3, 'I'),
                                   (4, 'E')]

def map_for_topaccount_customer_export(self, id, context=None):
    return "L3" if not id else MAP_BTW_REGIME_KLANT_TOPACCOUNT[id]
```

It supposed to return L3 if there isn't any ID to show for, the following piece is underlined in red and doesn't seem to work in my console:

> MAP_BTW_REGIME_KLANT_TOPACCOUNT[id]

Any idea why? Thanks a lot and sorry for the noobish question

Comment: Shouldn't `MAP_BTW_REGIME_KLANT_TOPACCOUNT ` be a `dict`, not a `list` of two-`tuple`s? Note: if it *was* a dictionary, your function becomes the much simpler `return MAP_BTW_REGIME_KLANT_TOPACCOUNT.get(id, "L3")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have defined there as `MAP_BTW_REGIME_KLANT_TOPACCOUNT` is a list of pairs, not a "map".

You can make it a `dict` by putting `dict()` around it:

```
MAP_BTW_REGIME_KLANT_TOPACCOUNT = dict([(1, 'L3'), (2, 'C'), (3, 'I'), (4, 'E')])
```

Or (as @jonrsharpe pointed out) it can be done more simply by defining the dictionary directly:

```
MAP_BTW_REGIME_KLANT_TOPACCOUNT = {1: 'L3', 2: 'C', 3: 'I', 4: 'E'}
```

Comment: That's a whole lot of brackets, a proper dictionary literal would be much neater.

Answer (score 1):

`MAP_BTW_REGIME_KLANT_TOPACCOUNT` is not a map, it's an association list. To make it into a map, you can define it as

```
MAP_BTW_REGIME_KLANT_TOPACCOUNT = dict([
    (1, 'L3'),
    (2, 'C'),
    (3, 'I'),
    (4, 'E')
])
```

But when you're at it, you could just as well turn it into a map directly:

```
MAP_BTW_REGIME_KLANT_TOPACCOUNT = {
    1: 'L3',
    2: 'C',
    3: 'I',
    4: 'E'
}
```